# Trying to understand 5M 5050 SMD LED power requirements and side effects

Tags: led-strip

Before I get into the whole question, let me just say that I am very new to electronics and this is really kind of a what-if scenario.  I do realize what is required to make the setup below work correctly, but I am curious as to the side effects to the following configuration.

So okay, let me just say that I do understand the basic mathematics regarding Power, voltage, current and resistance… However, I am curious as to what the side effects would be in a certain circumstances when it comes to powering a 5 meter strip of the 5050 SMD LEDs (300 warm white SMD LEDS) with built-in SMD resistors. Also the LED Strip would either be coated with epoxy or be in a silicone tube (so somewhat limited heat dissipation), but would be in a moderate environment (ranging between  50F to 80F)

Specifically, I have a 15volt, 1.4Amp wall wart power supply and I realize that this will only generate something like 22watts of power.  I also realize that the LED strip has a requirement of 12volts and 72 watts. (so the voltage is 3v to high and the wattage is significantly too low... even more so considering the fact that I should have a power supply with an extra 10 to 20% more wattage than needed).

However, what I am curious about is what would be the impact of connecting this power supply to this LED strip? The reason I ask is sort of three fold:

1) I was actually able to power the entire 5 meter LED strip with a small 12Volt 300mA power supply… Of course, it was somewhat dim but surprisingly it was evenly lit. This test only lasted about 5 minutes and the power supply did not seem to get warm in the slightest.  This and the fact that it even lit up the strip at all surprised me.  My guess is that over time the power supply would break down and it would either get really hot (and melt) or perhaps even damage the LED strip.  (Is this a correct assumption?)

2) I have read that LED strips lose voltage over there 5 meter length, so I was curious whether or not a 15volt 1.4Amp power supply would really cause a significant problem for the LED strip (in regards to the extra voltage) since it would generally lose significant voltage over its length anyway?   I even went so far as to connect the 15v power supply to a series of just 3 LEDs and while they were incredibly bright they did not burn out immediately (connected for about 30 seconds total and never burned out) as I would've expected them to do… Which makes me wonder how much damage would really be caused to a strip of 300 of the same LEDs? (or how significant it would impact their lifetime)

3) Lastly, I am curious as to the (side) effects to the power supply (again 15volts, 1.4Amp) and the strip of 300 warm white 5050 LEDs when connected *** IF *** the LED strip were only powered for approx 5 minutes at a time (basically in response to a motion sensor...and one that would rarely be triggered multiple times and even then would have a timeout of at least 5 seconds between triggers).

I realize that these are pretty large variations in requirements vs what I am supplying, so I guess I am really wondering how resilient the power supply and LED strips would be to this sort of situation (in that it is limited to a very short length of on-time due to the motion sensor being in a place that would probably only get triggered a couple times a day for about 5 minutes each time).  The power supply itself is actually a pretty high quality brand and the LED strips is of the cheap Chinese variety (if that factors in to any assumptions on outcome).

Of course there is always the idea of hooking it up in a controlled environment and see what happens, but I am curious as to any insights people might have on the expected resiliency of the components and the expected longevity of this specific sort of setup.

My guess is that the above setup would probably work for a period of time with an eventual and inevitable (potentially catastrophic) failure, but I am curious if that is really the case (especially the catastrophic part)?

Apologies if this question is sort of out of the ballpark for this forum, but my curiosity is piqued since I have seen alot of hacked LED setups on the web with really odd power configs and I was curious exactly how dangerous they are in reality (vs theoretically).

Comment: Quite a wall if text you got there so TL;DR. Roll back time eight years and your 5050 LED consisted of 3*50 mA leds. 3.5*50m*60*3 = 32 W per meter, so even back then they where underdriven in order not to overheat. I measued 42 W for 5 meter at 12.0 V. These days they use 3*20 mA chips and the current through them are even lower. Your 15 V is too high but 1.4 A might be borderline enough. Measure it!

Comment: Best we can do is guess, but I'd say the LED strip would be fine with a 15V PSU and very low duty cycles. However, the PSU might not be happy about having to supply more current than its intended to, maybe its outputs drop significantly, maybe peak output during this period will be too much for it, or maybe the voltage drop is so much that it's not even drawing that much current. There's really no way to tell for sure without  - as winny said - measuring it.

Comment: p.s.: There are many ways of improving your question and making it significantly more compact, that should help you get more attempts at answers.. i.e.: basically you want to know what are the possible drawbacks of powering a 12V LED strip with a PSU of higher voltage and lower current during low duty cycles.

Comment: Is the PSU a SMPS or iron core type (presumably the former). | when you load it with the strip what voltage does it drop to? [you must be able to answer that ][for at least 2 meanings of must :-) ]. Can you measure far end strip voltage in the above case (usually ccontact points are provided per section. || The question set is clear enough BUT there are too many unknowns. The regulator MAY have thermal protection and when overloaded reduce output to a level that maintains supportable  dissipation. This is a feature of MOST modern linear IC regulators and easily built into a smps ..

Comment: ... if the designer desires.  Some psus will happily shuit down to a supportable level, others will expire in flaming or whimpering ruin. || 300 LEDS 5m 6A. White LEDS almost always 3s in series so I/strig = 6A/100 = 60 mA/string. This is unlikely. You say "you realise" it will need 6A but give no LED spec or link , no psu link. You may have made incorrect assumptions. eg 300 x 20 mA = 6A but that does not account for 3 per string in series. SO you need to give as much hard data as possible. What are the resistor values? Why not use a properly rated psu (cost is modest). ...

Comment: You say 5m/time but do not give max duty cycle you wish to survive. If dissipation is really 2A x 12V = 25w then at about 5W/m you should be OK LED thermal dissipation wise. Probably :-). At 6A total mean current is 3A along strip. If you drop 1V you will hardly notice if at all so 1/3 Ohm along strip would be OK. With 15A psu you could drop maybe 3V and not care much and even at 12V. If 3 x LEDS in series drop 9v-10v, then at 12V you have 2 to 3V headroom across series R and at 15V you have more. You MAY discern some brighhtness change along 5m but quite likely not. ...

Comment: ... A  VERY small nu,ber of basic V measurements will tell you much. | What value are series R's?